# Dynamically binding to property of child controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Would it be possible to bind to Validation.HasErrors on any child control of a panel, without explicitly binding to every named control? Specifically i want to fire a trigger on a general style of a panel if any child control is in error state.

Thanks.

Comment: Can Attached Property help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an attached behavior that uses the `LogicalTreeHelper` (or `VisualTreeHelper` as a backup) to subscribe to the dependency property changed event of `Validation.HasErrors` for each child element [via `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx). From there you would just update your own attached property (say, `CompositeValidation.HasErrors`) and bind to that.